# UITextAutocapitalization fails after setting UITextfield to empty string

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have set up my Search Controller / SearchBar to capitalise words which is working as expected.

Set up using

```
searchController.searchBar.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.Words
```

It seems the next word is capitalised once the space bar is pressed.

My problem is if the clear the textfield using,

```
searchController.searchBar.text = ""
```

The autocapitalization is not active (? because I never pressed the space bar)

I've tried a few things such as

Adding a blank space prior to clearing the field

```
searchController.searchBar.text = " "
searchController.searchBar.text = ""
```

Resetting the firstResponder and also the UITextAutocapitalizationType

```
searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
searchController.searchBar.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.Words
```

Neither work.

Here is a screen grab...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Dont know why I didnt just do this,

```
searchController.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Problem Fixed...

If there is a better way let me know.